# Why my flutter rest API auth didn't works for debugging while on postman is successful

Tags: flutter, rest, dart, postman

I want to create Flutter Login/Logout/getVerify function for my task at college. For register and login is successfully  stores in my database, but when I hit the API called `getUserInfo` its not authenticated, while on my Postman is getting success for register - login - verified who login - logout. This is my auth.dart function:

```dart
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class AuthService with ChangeNotifier {
  late SharedPreferences _prefs;
  String? _sessionID;
  String? _uuid;
  String? get uuid => _uuid;
  String? get sessionID => _sessionID;

  AuthService(){
    _initPreferences();
  }

  Future<void> _initPreferences() async {
    try {
      _prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      _sessionID = _prefs.getString('sessionID');
      _uuid = _prefs.getString('uuid');
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error initializing SharedPreferences: $e');
    }
  }

  Future<bool> register(String name, String email, String password,
      String confPassword) async {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = {
      "name": name,
      "email": email,
      "password": password,
      "confPassword": confPassword
    };

    final String apiUrl = 'https://backend-dot-cycleme.et.r.appspot.com/users/register';

    final response = await http.post(
      Uri.parse(apiUrl),
      body: jsonEncode(data),
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
    );

    if (response.statusCode == 201) {
      // Registration was successful
      return true;
    } else {
      // Registration failed
      return false;
    }
  }


  Future<void> login(String email, String password) async {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = {
      "email": email,
      "password": password
    };

    final String apiUrl = "https://backend-dot-cycleme.et.r.appspot.com/login";

    final response = await http.post(
      Uri.parse(apiUrl),
      body: jsonEncode(data),
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
    );

    print('Login response status code: ${response.statusCode}');
    print('Login response body: ${response.body}');
    print('Request URL: ${Uri.parse('https://backend-dot-cycleme.et.r.appspot.com/me')}');
    print('Request Headers: ${{'Authorization': 'Bearer ${_sessionID ?? ''}'}}');


    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      _sessionID = json.decode(response.body)['loginResult']['sessionID'];
      _uuid = json.decode(response.body)['loginResult']['uuid'];
      // Save sessionID to SharedPreferences
      await _prefs?.setString('sessionID', _sessionID!);
      await _prefs?.setString('uuid', _uuid!);
      print('Session ID after login: $_sessionID');
      print('UUID after login: $_uuid');
      notifyListeners();
    } else {
      throw Exception('Login failed');
    }
  }

  Future<void> logout() async {
      final String apiUrl = "https://backend-dot-cycleme.et.r.appspot.com/logout";
      final response = await http.delete(
        Uri.parse(apiUrl),
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
      );
      print('Session ID before logout: $_sessionID');
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        _sessionID = null;
        await _prefs?.remove('sessionID');
        notifyListeners(); // Notify listeners that the authentication state has changed
        print('Session ID after logout: $_sessionID');

      } else {
        print("failed to logout");
      }
  }
 
  Future<Map<String, dynamic>> getUserInfo() async {

    if (_sessionID == null) {
      throw Exception('User is not authenticated');
    }
    try {
      print('Session ID before getUserInfo: $_sessionID'); // Add this line
      print('UUID before getUserInfo: $_uuid'); // Add this line

      final response = await http.get(
        Uri.parse('https://backend-dot-cycleme.et.r.appspot.com/me'),
        headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer ${_sessionID ?? ''}'},
      );

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        final data = json.decode(response.body);
        final uuid = data['uuid'];
        print('User UUID: $uuid');
        return data;
      } else {
        throw Exception('Failed to get user info - ${response.statusCode} ${response.body}');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      throw Exception('Failed to get user info - $e');
    }
  }

}
```

Why does it happens? Anyway I'm using `sessionID` instead of JWT.

My JSON response body of `getUserInfo`:

```json
{
    "uuid": "d2dd319e-7718-41b7-ad09-6857bb4cfc51",
    "name": "Irma",
    "email": "irma@getstack.com",
    "role": "user"
}
```

My JSON response body of login success:

```json
{
    "error": "false",
    "msg": "success",
    "loginResult": {
        "uuid": "d2dd319e-7718-41b7-ad09-6857bb4cfc51",
        "name": "Irma",
        "email": "irma@getstack.com",
        "role": "user",
        "sessionID": "vMRHpUNgBcEM3m_zhjXuWxLKWTzgxQuc"
    }
}
```

Comment: Either it can be error from the backend or you are not performing task completely.